# Getting the object an object is instantiated from

Tags: c++

I'm new at C++ and I am missing some terminology (couldn't ask a specific question to Google), so I'll try to be as clear as possible.

Let's say I have instantiated an object of class A. Then say, from a method of this object of class A, I create an object of class B.

In my class B, i want to use the object of class A as an argument (passed by reference if possible).

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your method of `class A` you can reference the current instance of `A` using the keyword `this`.  For example, you can provide `this` for `class A` to the constructor of `class B`.

My C++ syntax is a bit rusty, so here's a C# example that can be translated fairly literally to C++:

```
public class A
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        B b = new B(this);
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B(A parent) { // Do something with A, maybe store it in B for later reference
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, maybe I wasn't clear enough, but I was indeed looking for something like this. Thanks everyone for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to tell what you mean by `use the object of class A as an argument`.  You mean the one it was created from?  Other than that it sounds like you're describing a circular dependancy.  Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
//B.h
class A;  //DO NOT INCLUDE.  This is called "forward declaration"
class B {
    A& parent;  //All `A` in this file must be reference or pointer
public:
    B(A& a);
};
```

.

```
//A.h
#include "B.h"
class A {
    B function();  //since it's not reference or pointer, must have include
};
```

.

```
//B.cpp
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"
void B::function(A& a)
: parent(a)
{}
```

.

```
//A.cpp
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"
B A::function()
{
    return B(*this);
}
```

Keep in mind, if `B::parent` is a reference, you cannot assign a `B` to another, you lose all copy semantics.  If you need those, you'll have to make `parent` a pointer instead.  Which is recommended, but you asked for reference specifically.  A reference also requires that the `A` remain in memory as long as the `B` exists, which can be a tricky guarantee to make.

Comment: As an aside, this is called a Forward Declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the creating object into constructor as a reference:

```
B b(*this);
```

Where you have:

```
class B {
public:
   B(const A &creator_) : creator(creator_) { }

private:
   const A& creator;
}
```

;